# Can't access GlobalConfiguration.Configuration from .Net 5.0 WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac, webapi

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` seems unavailable in a new ASP.NET Core WebApi project (.Net 5.0) .

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Api" project. (Target framework: .NET 5.0, Lang: C#)
2. Add this line anywhere to your code: `var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;`

e.g. Add it to Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
        var c = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;    // this line was added
        Configuration = configuration;
}
```

3. You'll need a package for `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration`
   which seems the correspond with the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost` Nuget package, so install it with:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -Version 5.2.7
```

4. Run the application, to see it fail at our new code line with the exception below:

```
System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Could not load type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteTable'
  from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
  Source=System.Web.Http.WebHost
  StackTrace:
   at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.<>c.<CreateConfiguration>b__11_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.get_Configuration()
   at AspNetCore5._0.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\work\AspNetCore5.0\Program.cs:line 17
```

**What I am ultimately trying to achieve...** is to use AutoFac as my dependency resolver (I got this working). But when I follow [AutoFac's documentation on FilterProviders](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#provide-filters-via-dependency-injection) to created my own custom `Filters` (e.g. ModelValidationFilter, ResponseFilter, ExceptionFilter), it requires that I obtain `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`. [AutoFac documentation on obtaining GlobalConfiguration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html?highlight=filters#get-the-httpconfiguration) suggests that I obtain `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` for 'standard IIS hosting' as follows:

`var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;`

... but it clearly fails.

I'll appreciate any help or advice on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core is not the same thing as ASP.NET or ASP.NET WebAPI, and whilst many things such as controllers require only minor tweaks to port, configuration and routing are very different.

Since your ultimate goal is to install AutoFac as the dependency resolver, try following AutoFac's [documentation for ASP.NET Core](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @yaakov (much appreciated!). Is "netcoreapp3.1" preferred to "net5.0"? I would like to use the framework where things are steering towards. (I also noticed there is even a target for "netcoreapp5.0" - would this be better than "netcoreapp3.1"). In the meantime, I'll work through the documentation as you've suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Yes use net5.0 if you want the latest (unless you require LTS in which case stick with netcoreapp3.1 or wait for net6.0). The netcoreapp5.0 moniker was part of the earlier development of net5.0, don't use it

Comment: Thanks @pinkfloydx33! much appreciated!

Comment: @yaakov, I have followed your instruction. However, the "filter" documentation is framework independent: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html?highlight=filter#register-the-filter
So, I'm still stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @z0mbi3 The docu you linked is still for the old ASP.NET WebAPI and not ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core has an inbuilt dependency injection support for all of its filters. So you don’t need to do anything special.

Comment: Thank you @ckuri, however, as stated, I would like to use AutoFac as my DI framework, for various valid reasons. So I still need to find a solution to this. But more importantly, the issue is not with AutoFac at all. The real issue is that I can't obtain "GlobalConfiguration.Configuration" from the WebApi.

Comment: @z0mbi3 Yaakov has given you a link how to use Autofac in ASP.NET Core. Filter configuration is done the standard ASP.NET Core way (because ASP.NET Core is highly modular and doesn’t care which DI framework you use), which is described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0 There is no GlobalConfiguration in ASP.NET Core, because configuration is done differently.

Comment: Thanks @ckuri (and yaakov). I have managed to get AutoFac Filters working. You were right, it doesn't require GlobalConfiguration.Configuration at all. Thanks for all your help!